# Why is this simple text replacement code not working?

Tags: c#, char, docx, spaces, novacode-docx

With text like this in a *.docx file:

> ```
> I scream.  You scream.  We all scream for ice cream.
>
> I scream.You scream.We all scream for ice cream.
> ```

...(IOW, two spaces between sentences in the first case, and no spaces in the second case) I want to force one and only one space between the sentences, so it ends up like so:

> ```
> I scream. You scream. We all scream for ice cream.
>
> I scream. You scream. We all scream for ice cream.
> ```

But this code:

```
// 65..90 are A..Z; 97..122 are a..z
const int firstCapPos = 65;
const int lastCapPos = 90;
const int firstLowerPos = 97;
const int lastLowerPos = 122;

    . . .

// This will change sentences like this: "I scream.You scream.We all scream of ice cream." ...to this: "I scream. You scream. We all scream of ice cream."
private void SpacifySardinizedLetters(string filename)
{
    using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
    {
        for (int i = firstCapPos; i <= lastCapPos; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)i;
            string originalStr = string.Format(".{0}", c);
            string newStr = string.Format(". {0}", c);
            document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
        }
        for (int i = firstLowerPos; i <= lastLowerPos; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)i;
            string originalStr = string.Format(".{0}", c);
            string newStr = string.Format(". {0}", c);
            document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
        }
        document.Save();
    }
}

// This will change sentences like this: "I scream.  You scream.  We all scream of ice cream." ...to this: "I scream. You scream. We all scream of ice cream."
private void SnuggifyLooseyGooseySentenceEndings(string filename)
{
    using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
    {
        for (int i = firstCapPos; i <= lastCapPos; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)i;
            string originalStr = string.Format(".  {0}", c);
            string newStr = string.Format(". {0}", c);
            document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
        }
        for (int i = firstLowerPos; i <= lastLowerPos; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)i;
            string originalStr = string.Format(".  {0}", c);
            string newStr = string.Format(". {0}", c);
            document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
        }
        document.Save();
    }
}
```

...only works for the scrunched together sentences - The ones with two spaces between them fails to change. Why? Is there a bug in my code, or in the docx library?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. This is not a free debugging service.

Comment: What did you try? Add logging, for example to see what you are replacing with what. Do you actually call the method that replaces `.  {0}` with `{. {0}`? Can you provide a small example that reproduces the problem? So: create a `.docx` file with a sentence like `Foo.  Bar`, and to verify the replacement works only call `document.ReplaceText(".  B", ". B");`. You need to isolate the issue.

Comment: I stepped through it, and it looks fine; it simply doesn't replace the two spaces with one.

Comment: Yes, I am calling the method - I put a breakpoint in it. And with my document, the no-space-between-them sentences get altered as they should, but the two-spaces-beween-them sentences do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909150/why-is-this-simple-text-replacement-code-not-working#comment31387833_20909150), downloaded [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/), created a Microsoft Word document and ran this code from a project referencing the DocX library:

```
// Contains "Foo.Bar and Foo.  Bar"
string filename = "TestWordDocument.docx";

using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
{
    document.ReplaceText(".B", ". B");
    document.ReplaceText(".  B", ". B");
    document.Save();
})
```

And the Word file, prior containing:

```
Foo.Bar and Foo.  Bar
```

Afterwards contains:

```
Foo. Bar and Foo. Bar
```

So, works for me.

Edit: I ran your code on a file containing the first line from your question, and it works. Are you sure you're running this code and that you're looking at the correct file?

Comment: Very odd; with a new document, it works for me now. The first one (the one that didn't work) contained text I pasted in to Word from Visual Studio, that's the only difference between the non-working and the working docx.

Comment: Possibly it doesn't work when the text is split into multiple runs?  Unzip your docx and look at the XML in document.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a regular expression instead:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpression;

string text = readFromDocx();
string newText = Regex.Replace( text, @"\.[^\S\n]*(\w)",
    m => string.Format( ". {0}", m.Groups[ 1 ] ) )
```

The double negation is meant to match all whitespaces except newlines, normally included in the `\s` specifier.

Comment: Will this work with a .docx file, replacing everything in the doc?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon text is a string variable and the method returns a string as well, so it will work if you are able to read the text as a string and write back the result to the file

Comment: I don't think that will work, as the DOCX library does not have a concept of lines. Maybe the simplest solution is to just replace all "  " with " " manually.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon this should not be a problem

Answer (score -2):

Try this code of docX.Replace() easy to change text from something text to another text.

```
static void Replace(string filename, string a, string b)
    {
        using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
        {
            document.ReplaceText(a, b);

            document.Save();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This answer is more or less a duplicate of the already accepted answer posted by @CodeCaster.